# Collapsing toolbar is collapsed by default

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a problem with `CollapsingToolbar`. The problem in that by default I need to have collapsed toolbar when Activity just has been created. If I do that through the code with `appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, false)` in `onCreate()` method, I see expanded toolbar for the first time and then it collapsed in a second. I need to remove that and display collapsed toolbar immediately.

**UPD:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
      app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
      app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
  </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 25):

`AppBarLayout` has an `expanded` attribute. Try setting that to false.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:expanded="false">
```

This worked for me in my test project when I plugged in your layout and added that one line.

I was able to do this with versions 23.0.1 and 23.4.0 of the design support library.

Comment: This has no result (

Comment: What happens, is collapsing toolbar still fully expanded?

Comment: This works in my test project. Please post your entire layout XML with `CoordinatorLayout` in it.

Comment: @kris_larson, yes it is still initialize expanded and then begin collapsed

Comment: @Near1999 please post your layout XML.

Comment: Updated my post. Sorry for being so slow :(

Comment: Updated my answer.  This worked for me no problem.  What version of design support lib are you using?  If you are still having problems, post your entire layout XML with the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: I catch another bug ) I made my list nestedScrollingEnabled to false and everything works fine with it, but if I swipe down toolbar - it is collapsing :( After creating new activity and finish it everything works fine, toolbar doesn't collapse with swipe down on it. Do You know what can it be?

Comment: Here is my entire layout xml https://codeshare.io/H7znp I'm using 24.1.1 design support lib

Comment: Nov 2019, latest Google/Android libs: works in layout preview, works when I run the app.